# For loop returning completely wrong value using power function

Tags: javascript

As you can see int he code below I separate the n variable and convert back to an integer array. When I put these numbers into my for loop they come out in the billions. Any help would be greatly appreciated.

```
var n = [86]
var p = [1]

n = n.toString().split("").map(function(value) {
    return(parseInt(value))
})
var total = 0;
for(i=0;i<n.length;i++) {
    total += (Math.pow(n[i],(p+i))
}
console.log(total)
```

Answer (score 1):

You need the conversion from strings to numbers and you are adding an array to numbers.

You cannot sum an array to an integer [1]+0, it doesn't result in a number. It will do a concatenation.

```js
var n = [86]
var p = [1]
n = n.toString().split("").map(val => Number(val))
var total = 0;
for (i = 0; i < n.length; i++) {
  total += Math.pow(n[i], (p[0] + i))
}
console.log(total);
```

Answer (score 0):

`p` is an array not an individual number, in your for loop, when it is running `(p+i)`, that value ends up being `10` and `11`. So your first loop is running `Math.pow(8,10)` and the second time it runs it is running `Math.pow(6,11)`, which, will result in a number in the billions